# Covariant array subtyping and polymorphic arrays

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism, covariance

In Java covariant array subtyping means that if `A` is a subtype of `B` then `A[]` is considered a subtype of `B[]`. I read that covariant array subtyping is a bad design choice and instead polymorphic arrays is the right design choice. But what exactly does polymorphic arrays mean?

Comment: An array of `A`s is `A[]` not `List<A>`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bhesh Gurung pointed out in his comment, *array* covariance has nothing to do with generic classes like `List<T>`. Array covariance means that if class `B` extends class `A`, then type `B[]` is assignable to `A[]`.

The reason they did this in Java was to allow methods like [`Arrays.equals(Object[], Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) to work back before they added generics to Java. Basically, they wanted a method that takes an `Object[]` to be able to accept any type of array. This is a bad choice because it can lead to runtime type errors. For example:

```
Object[] objs = (Object[]) new Integer[1];
objs[0] = "Hello"; // Compiles, but throws runtime error
```

A polymorphic array would be like how arrays work in the Scala language. Rather than declaring `new Integer[10]`, you'd be able to do something like `new Array<Integer>(10)`. I think this might be preferable because it would let you do things like initialize arrays of generic type, or create arrays of things with generic types. E.g., `new List<String>[10]`.